# how to get slice of type struct defined inside another struct using go and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, slice, mgo

mongodb collections

```
employee
{
  _id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"qwert",
  "emp_id":111,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
}
{
_id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"asdfg",
  "emp_id":121,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
}
department{
_id:ObjectId(),
"dept_id":11,
"dept_name":"XYZ",
"description":"decs",
}
```

My Go Code is

```
 type Employee struct {
    EmployeeName  string             `json:"emp_name" bson:"emp_name"`
    EmployeeID    int                `json:"emp_id" bson:"emp_id"`
    EmployeeDept  String             `json:"emp_dept" bson:"emp_dept"`
    EmpDepartment Department         `json:"department" bson:"department"` 
}
 type Department struct {
    DepartmentID    int                `json:"dept_id" bson:"dept_id"`
    DepartmentName  string             `json:"dept_name" bson:"dept_name"` 
    Description     string             `json:"description" bson:"description"` 
    EmployeeList    []Employee         `json:"employee_list" bson:"employee_list"`
}

collection := session.DB("db").C("department")
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$match": bson.M{
        "dept_name": "xyz",
          }},
        {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "employee",
        "localField":   "dept_name",
        "foreignField": "emp_dept",
        "as":           "employee_list",
    }},
        {"$unwind": "$employee_list"},
    })

err = pipeline.One(&departmentEmployees)
```

It shows Department Details with Employee Slice empty

I want to get deartment info of 'XYZ' dept with list of all employees working inside that department.
I have uploaded my collections and struct as Example

Comment: Your Go model doesn't seem to match your database structure inferred from your query. Please post what collections you have, with example documents.

Comment: @icza i have post the collections plz could you help me why i am getting empty employee list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Department` struct has a `EmployeeList []Employee` field, so if you plan to unmarshal the aggregation result into `Department` values, you have to remove the `$unwind` stage.

Something like this should work:

```
collection := session.DB("db").C("department")
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{
        "dept_name": "xyz",
    }},
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "employee",
        "localField":   "dept_name",
        "foreignField": "emp_dept",
        "as":           "employee_list",
    }},
})

var departments []*Department
err = pipeline.One(&departments)
```

Also you have a `EmployeeDept String` field in `Employee`, I don't know what your `String` type is, maybe it's just `string`?

Comment: yes it is string actually. thanku so much it helped me alot.